# Fast Charging by Qualcomm 3.0- impact on battery?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

I am thinking of buying [HTC one A9](http://www.htc.com/in/smartphones/htc-one-a9/)

My only concern is with fast charging . I have read this thread [How does fast charging work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58961/how-does-fast-charge-work) and understood the downside is mainly on battery life. Accepted answer seems to be  based on Qualcomm 2.0 and not the latest

HTC one A9 uses the latest Qualcomm 3.0 technology which is claimed to be [38% more efficient](http://www.theverge.com/2015/9/15/9329299/qualcomm-snapdragon-820-quick-charge-3).  I am confused , whether less charging time means less damage to battery life or more?

My question

**Is it better or worse for battery life compared to earlier technology and how / why?**

Comment: Keep in mind that you can just use a regular charger instead of a fast charger too...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Short Answer

From *battery health* point of view, Qualcomm Quick Charge 3.0 is *comparatively* better than Qualcomm  Quick Charge 2.0, since *power used for charging is better controlled, resulting in lesser heat*

---

## Quick review of concepts (optional read)

*Essential concepts  are summarised here in bullet form. Some of these have been elaborated in  [How does Fast Charge work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133806/131553)*

1. **Charging Efficiency:**  Conventional (not fast) charging efficiency is [close to 100%](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries)

   > Charge efficiency is about 99 percent and the cell remains cool during charge.
2. **Heating of Battery while Charging:**  is inevitable, given the space (lack of) for heat dissipation but needs to be in limits - [All about Battery Chargers](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/all_about_chargers) says

   > Li-ion should not rise more than 10ºC (18ºF) above ambient when reaching full charge.
3. **Battery charging stages** each requiring different *Power* (= *Voltage* multiplied by *Current*) as depicted in [Fig 1](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries). As an example, as battery charges up, it slowly draws less and less current, which is partly why it takes longer to charge the last 20 percent than the first.
4. **Adverse effects of quick charging:** Quick charging, turbo charging, adaptive fast charging, rapid charging are different names meaning the same- fast charging. OEMs have  [implemented it under various trade names](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/06/12/quick-rapid-turbo-and-fast-charging-explained-what-you-need-to-know-about-charging-your-smartphone/) ) speeds up charging process by increasing power. This has *adverse effects* on health of battery

   a)  **Battery is not fully charged**, since it does not spend adequate time in all the stages of charging (which happens during conventional charging)

   b)  **Heating up of battery**. Power which cannot be absorbed by the battery (for charging) is dissipated as Heat, which [is the biggest enemy of battery](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_at_high_and_low_temperatures).  *Ideally*,   [Fast charging of most batteries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/all_about_chargers) should be

   > limited to a temperature of 5 to 45°C (41 to 113°F); for best results consider narrowing the temperature bandwidth to between 10°C and 30°C (50°F and 86°F)

   c)   As a combined effect of a) and b) above, battery life is adversely affected both in *short and long* term (incomplete charge and reduced life cycles )

---

## Long Answer

1. [Qualcomm Quick Charge 2.0](http://www.androidauthority.com/quick-charge-3-0-explained-643053/) supported four modes at varying power levels, 5 volts/2amps, 9V/2A, 12V/1.67A, and a 20 volt option
2. [Qualcomm Quick Charge 3.0](http://www.androidauthority.com/quick-charge-3-0-explained-643053/)  has major new feature  **INOV (Intelligent Negotiation for Optimum Voltage)**, which allows for

> - A fine tuned power output and a more optimized charging cycle. Quick Charge 3.0’s INOV communicates with the device to request *any voltage between 3.2V and 20V at 200mV increments, allowing for a wider selection of voltages*
> - INOV has the added benefit of being able to ***dynamically*** adjust the charging voltage over the battery charging cycle

( Linked source has a video explaining this and graphical comparison is pasted in the  section at end of answer )

3. This granular variation of voltage to control power , [results in](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/09/15/qualcomm-introduces-quick-charge-3-0-27-faster-and-38-more-power-efficient-than-quick-charge-2-0/)

> - 27% faster charging than Quick Charge 2.0 (2x faster than the original Quick Charge 1.0) while
> - Reducing power dissipation by 45%
> - Increasing power efficiency by 38%, and being friendlier to the battery life cycle.
> - You're looking at 4 times faster charging compared to regular charging, and devices capable of jumping from 0% to 80% in about 35 minutes.

To summarise, *granular fine control on voltage and in turn on power supplied for charging* is the key innovation  that results in these improved figures.  Qualcomm Quick Charge 2.0 had only **one  voltage level** relevant to mobile devices- 5V, whereas Qualcomm Quick Charge 3.0 has  **9 variations possible** from 3.2V to 5V in steps of 200 mV. This granularity offers tight control on power delivered for charging in a *dynamic* manner as required

Point to note, is that *controlled power supply for charging means less power wasted, therefore less heat and better for battery*

4. **To good to be true?** This technology looks impressive but there is a *major caveat*

   - All comparisons are with reference to Quick Charge 2.0 and comparative figures for version 2.0 over Quick Chargeversion 1.0 or with conventional charging **are not available in public domain** ( for obvious reasons, for that matter, similar figures for Qualcomm Quick Charge 2.0 over 1.0 are also not available)
   - These figures reflect the *capability of Qualcomm Quick Charge  technology*. Realization in device depends on hardware and OS implementation
5. **Compatability with old chargers:** Quick Charge 3.0 will be backward compatible with the technology's previous iterations (so your old chargers and cables should still work), and can be implemented with USB Type-C, USB Type-A, MicroUSB, and proprietary connectors.

**Conclusion**

1. *Qualcomm Quick Charge 3.0 is safer than Quick Charge 2.0 as far as battery health* is concerned as indicated by figures shared
2. Whether you get the claimed performance is yet to be seen. HTC A one 9 appears to be the first device to hit the market with this technology and we should get better feedback as more devices enter with this technology
3. Charging by power pack/ power bank (to avoid being in a battery drained situation and when you don't have access to mains) is a better option over fast charging
4. Regular charging using a standard 5V 2A ( conventional charger ) should be preferred mode with fast charging resorted to *when actually needed*
5. Most of the battery apps on Play Store measure the battery temperature also. You could measure the temperature after charging and compare with guidelines mentioned at 2, 5 of "Quick Review of Concepts" to get an idea of how it affects your device

---

## Additional Information to dig deeper

- **List of supported devices:** Qualcomm [Quick Charge 3.0](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon/quick-charge) lists out the devices using various versions of its technology, though probably slow to update
- **Evolution of Qualcomm Quick Charge technology:**  Comparison between [**3.0 vs 2.0 vs 1.0**](http://www.androidauthority.com/quick-charge-3-0-explained-643053/)

[image]

- **Choosing a Charger:** HTC A one 9 does not come with a charger ! This [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/one-a9/accessories/tronsmart-quick-charge-3-0-usb-turbo-t3236022) discusses chargers and may be of use

Comment: What do you mean with "charging by power pack"?

Comment: @JopV. Power bank which is commercially available to charge batteries when you don't have access to mains

Comment: And that's better for your battery than regular non-fast charging? That seems unintuitive. Is it better because it is even slower?

Comment: @JopV. Thanks for pointing out the confusion. You are right. What I was referring to is the use case of fast charging to have enough juice is not good , it makes sense rather to have a power bank. Good power banks do control charging speed too. But given that QC is backward compatible, using a regular charger when you have access to mains is preferred. Thanks again for catching that mistake. Edited solution

Comment: registered to say this answer is amazing. It could further improve by "bolding out" some conclusions: any form of fast charge, QC. Dash, Adaptive, might be faster but are NOT BETTER than standard SLOW, intelligent charge for NOT DEGRADING battery cycles over time. Another important conclusion is that QC technologies compare over previous gens, as the answer says, obviously for hiding the above. Fast charges are a marketing stunt and together with irreplaceable bats, a clever, convoluted way for companies to implement ___PLANNED OBSOLENCE___ and get you to buy a new phone every 2.5 years

Comment: @leRobot: Thanks a lot - please feel free to edit by making **bold** what you think would help. Also agree with you on other points but  *discerning* readers will figure it out. Elsewhere in other answers, I brought out the planned obsolescence bit and avoided being repetitive :)