# OnePlus Dash Charging on the OnePlus Three

Tags: charging, oneplus-two, oneplus-3

The OnePlus Three is out and I got mine yesterday. It comes with speed charging (which OnePlus calls "Dash Charging"). As I read, it only works if the plug it comes with and the USB type C cable it comes with is used.

I'm worried that the battery will suffer from frequent speed charging when it's not needed (for example when charging over night or when at home for a long time during the day). Is this concern justified or won't it have a significant impact on the overall life span (not only a single charge-discharge cycle) of the battery? If it isn't ignore the next paragraph.

Is there a software solution for this, other than installing a custom rom by which it'd lose the speed charging functionality altogether? If there isn't, I could either charge it on my laptop (USB 3.0), on my Nexus 4 plug (1.2 A), or buy a different USB type C cable (and use the original OnePlus plug, in the last case). Which do you consider the best option?

---

It [has been suggested](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148918/oneplus-dash-charging-on-the-oneplus-three#comment191076_148918) by [@bmdixon](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/30530/bmdixon) that this is a duplicate of [that question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/does-constant-charging-harm-my-android-cellphone) which is not the case because neither does that question take into account additional wear on the battery caused by speed charging, nor does my question necessitate keeping the phone connected to the charger for an extended period of time after the battery has already been fully charged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does constant charging harm my Android cellphone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/does-constant-charging-harm-my-android-cellphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Oneplus 3 Dash Charging is said to be Oppo VOOC fast charging named differently ([Source](http://www.trustedreviews.com/opinions/what-is-dash-charge-oneplus-3))
- The damage to batteries is attributed mainly due to heating and shorter battery life (see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/138597/131553)). One Plus Three [website](https://oneplus.net/in/3/dashcharge) says

> Dash Charge carries more current than other fast charging solutions, and at lower temperatures. Normally, heat generated through charging is dissipated in the phone itself - this causes performance issues during active charging, throttling CPU and GPU speeds. By shifting the power management system and heat dispersion elements to our Dash Charge Adapter, very little heat ever reaches your OnePlus 3.

AFAIK there is hardly any literature available on VOOC, or the improvements made by One Plus, so it is up to you to believe it or not.

- If you don't - then, amongst the options listed by you:

  (a) Charging it off the USB port of computer- USB Type C can supply only 900 mA, which would take 4 plus hours to charge from 0 to 100% . (Plug in values [Battery Charge Time Calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/batterychgcalc.html).

  (b) The Nexus 4 adapter would take about 3 hours (using the calculator above)

  (c) [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/nexus2cee_2016-06-14-17_19_31-OnePlus-3-Dash-Charge-OnePlus.net_-728x442.png) says any Type C charger would work fine (of course, without Dash charging) and that seems logical and I have read of it working on the Oneplus Two also (although the Oneplus Two didn't have fast charging), but you **cannot** use the supplied adapter as mentioned in [this](http://www.trustedreviews.com/opinions/what-is-dash-charge-oneplus-3) review, and that is to be expected.

  - IMO, third option- buying USB type C cable and charger is superior if time is faster charging (but not as fast as quick charge) and options (a) and (b) are fine if time is not a constraint and you are worried about the battery.

**Edit:** [Tamoghna in his comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148918/oneplus-dash-charging-on-the-oneplus-three/148924?noredirect=1#comment191247_148924) being an owner of device, has clarified that  **any Type C adapter can be used** , of course without Dash Charging. Thanks Tamoghna. For the OP , it makes the choice easier of going with *third option*

- [Dash Charging Speed Analysis](https://www.xda-developers.com/dash-charge-speed-analysis-even-with-heavy-usage-your-phone-will-charge-rapidly-and-stay-cool/) has detailed tests highlighting the ability of Dash Charge to charge to full

**Edit 2**

Additional inputs from [OEM](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/in-response-to-the-type-c-cable-discussions.412344/)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "But you cannot use the supplied adapter as mentioned in review and that is to be expected"? Do you mean that it's to be expected that it can't be changed in the setting of the official ROM the phone comes with? (I don't see how that's mentioned in the linked review but I might be guessing wrong.)

Comment: 1. Dash charging workload is in charger as quoted from 1+3 site. The charger, cable and OS all have to be in sync to make it happen 2. Review  says you **have** to use OEM charger and cable- most OEMs tie down the charger and cable working (for possibly revenue or proprietary reasons) . Some go to extremes- Moto X , my device, cable is fused with charger. So the statement was from both technical and practices followed by OEM

Comment: @beeshyams, what you said about the OEM charging accessories being **required** to be used, is wrong. You can use any adapter, as long as you don't care about the Dash charging. What you shouldn't do, however, is use the OP3 Dash charger for charging any other USB Type-C device, as that might fry the battery due to the higher current (It might work though, as the charger can (supposedly) regulate the current output depending on the device). I don't have another USB Type-C device to test the Dash charger for safety.

Comment: @beeshyams, I own an OP3, and I have tested this myself. Need any other source?

Comment: Oh, and BTW, for any OP3 related questions, and OxygenOS related ones, drop me a ping in chat if I don't catch it otherwise. I'll be editing my profile page.