# Are all the 2 amp Chargers are "Quick Chargers"?

Tags: charging, xiaomi

According to Qualcomm's website they use some modern technology which will result in quick charging and according to a blog on android police if you want to check a charger is a quick charger then check its ampere rating if it is 2 amp or not...So according to that all quick chargers are 2 amp chargers but is vice versa true?
Now why i am asking this? I have a xiaomi redmi 3s prime and i takes 3 hours to charge with a 2 amp charger(which came in the box) so is it because its battery is 4000 mah or is it because it doesn't support quick charging

Comment: no, quick charging, turbo charging are different technologies. check mi forums to learn about their new techniques. but it is true that a charger with 2 amp o/p will charge your phone more quickly. i have a Xiaomi RedMi Note 3 and i have tested different charger and phone combinations. it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 2A chargers **are not quick chargers** and all quick chargers **are not necessarily** 2A ([Qualcomm Quick Charge 3.0](http://www.androidauthority.com/quick-charge-3-0-explained-643053/) is 3.2 V)

- [USB standard 3.0](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0) in   lays down standards of 10 W: 5 V, 2 A  for *smartphones and tablets*
- `Power = Voltage multiplied by Current` and this equation determines charging speed. When you use a 2A charger instead of 1A charger, charging speed increases . You can
  calculate the charging time required using the [Battery Charge Time Calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/batterychgcalc.html) ( choose efficiency of charging at 90 % if your battery is not too old ). Your device is probably supplied 2A charger since the battery is big and charging with 1A would take long. You can plug in the values in the calculator and see for yourself
- *Quick charging / fast charging* of entirely different.  Basic principle is to increase the power supplied in charging by increasing *power*, either by increasing *voltage or current or both*. See this for more details [How does fast-charge work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/58961/131553)

Comment: Isn't QC 1.0 5V/2A? That's about the only 2A standard and it's out of date, though.

Comment: @AndyYan: it is. That is what I meant by  *all quick chargers are not 2A*. Will add *necessarily* to make it more clear. Thanks

Comment: @AndyYan : even QC 2.0 can be . See table at end of answer http://android.stackexchange.com/a/138678/131553

Comment: Yeah but I thought that's just for downwards compatibility with 1.0...

Comment: Nope functionally also. Backward compatibility is a must for brand specific fast charging- there are so many kinds