# How do I know that a charger is a Turbo Charger for my Moto

Tags: charging, motorola-moto-g

I have a bunch of USB chargers lying around and I wanted to clear the mess. Is there an easy way of knowing which ones support the Turbo Charging function of my Moto G5?

Does every company have its own version of fast charging or is there pre-agreed protocols that are negotiated between phones / batteries & chargers.

I do have this monitoring app "Ampere" installed & it shows 1630 mA right now as the charging current at a 24% battery level.

Can one tell from this whether we are in fast charge territory?

Also, can one typically tell from the specs printed on the charger itself? e.g. This charger shows

> Model C P49L SPN5967A Output 5.2V 2A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does every company have its own version of fast charging or is there pre-agreed protocols that are negotiated between phones / batteries & chargers.

Yes. See this answer [How does fast-charge work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/58961/131553). This list is not exhaustive and doesn't cover all types but get the idea

> I do have this monitoring app "Ampere" installed & it shows 1630 mA ....

Yes. It's a fast charger, normal charger will not charge usually beyond 1100 mA

> Model C P49L SPN5967A

Google it. You will find listed on Amazon and in the supported phones, you will see that they ( I didn't verify all) support fast charging

> How do I know that a charger is a Turbo Charger for my Moto

It doesn't seem to be going by the list of supported phones. But be aware that *some or most* turbo chargers do fast charging and vice versa. But it's best to get one that specifically supports your device

Comment: You can input the battery size in the calculator linked in the answer and see how long normal charging would take at 1.2A and compare that how long it takes to charge with your turbo charger https://android.stackexchange.com/a/161482/131553