# Can you charge a Qualcomm Quick Charge device without a supported charger?

Tags: charging

I have a laptop with a 20V 2.25A charger and a phone that supports QC 3.0. In theory, 3.0 has support for up to 20V, but I am not sure if I can use the laptop charger with the phone given that the charger is not necessarily QC approved. Both devices are USB C.

[Phone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N9541P6)

[Charger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XGMKDCF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick charging is not just about Voltage or current in isolation. It is about varying both to deliver the right amount of *power* ( = product of voltage and current ) as required. Read more here [Fast Charging by Qualcomm 3.0- impact on battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/138597/131553)

Besides, the device detects if the charger is quick charge or not. If it is not, then it acts as of it is connected to a normal charger, which is rated 5V, 2A , far lower than the one you want to try

To answer your question - NO, not advised