# Will charging a phone with a different USB *cable* affect the battery life?

Tags: usb, battery, charging

I recently realized that I've been using the wrong USB cable to charge my Moto X Play(2015) for probably a couple weeks. The phone is specifically designed to charge very quickly with its' default charger, and I've been feeling like the battery life has dropped slightly over the past week or two (roughly the duration of time that I would have been using the wrong cable.)

I was using the correct wall-plug, but the wrong USB cable. I'm hoping that the chip to control fast-charging is in the wall-plug and that the cable wouldn't matter, but again I feel like the battery is dropping faster now than when I got it only a few weeks ago. Not by any great margin, but enough to be frustrating, considering it's my own stupid fault.

If anyone has any idea whether this would cause any damage to the battery, I would really just like to know for the future. Feel really stupid, the only reason I got this phone was for the large battery capacity it has.

Comment: Beshyams provided [a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/142039/16575) already. For additional details, also see our [charging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/charging/info).

Answer (score 2):

- Moto X Play supports fast charging, though this [review](http://m.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_x_play-review-1325.php) says a fast charger is not supplied with it, maybe they supplied it subsequently
- Fast charging needs to be supported by the USB cable as well. The D+ and D- pins of the cable negotiate the charging voltage and current with the device, in tune with the charging circuitry in the charger (see [Overview of USB Charging](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5801) for more details
- If a cable/ charger that does not support fast charging is used, there is **no harm caused** -  charging will be normal charging instead of fast charging. In the case of cable, it is because it may not be designed to carry adequate fast charging current, which is usually higher than normal charging

*Additional Information*  you may like to refer:

1. [How does fast charge work](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133806/131553)
2. [How to choose micro USB cable for my device](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/134970/131553)