# Can I charge my phone with many different charger speed types?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, stock-android, nexus-6p

I have a nexus 6p, and various different chargers which I bought for the phone. One is a slow USB charger (comes with the box).

Another is a type c to type c cable connected to the AnkerCore 20100+ battery pack (this charges quick charge too but I charge that with a USB mini so the current is different).

I also have a charging dock and sometimes use my computer to charge it, along with a wall charger with the highest speed.

Does this effect the battery in any way and does it effect the time before I have to charge it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement the answer of acejavelin and elaborate on other aspects

- Fast charging is believed to cause damage to both the short term and long term health of battery. Former by not giving enough battery performance for charge and latter by losing capacity to hold charge. Think of drinking soft drinks and maybe a slice of pizza to fill your stomach- your body does not get as much balanced nutrients as it would from a regular meal and you can't do as much work before feeling hungry (*short term*). If you keeping filling your stomach that way for a long time, effects are obvious (*long term*) - example is little stretched but makes sense if you think of [empty calories](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_calorie)
- Same is explained  technically in answers [How does fast-charge work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/58961/131553) and [Fast Charging by Qualcomm 3.0- impact on battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/138597/131553)
- Technical details for Nexus phones  which use fast charging of USB type is [Android phone "charging slowly": How to make it faster](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/143031/131553)

> And what if I charge the device a bit with one charger and a little with another charger?

Well it's like filling your stomach with pizza sometimes and eating balanced meals sometimes. Not as good as always doing the latter but better than always doing the former!

Related: [Will charging a phone with a different USB *cable* affect the battery life?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/142037/131553)

Answer (score 1):

All the chargers should work, to a varying degree... if they are QC compatible, the phone may charge faster than "normal", if not, the phone will attempt to draw current up to the maximum capacity of the charger or the phones "normal" limit.

*Does this effect the battery in any way and does it effect the time before I have to charge it again?*

Yes, of course it does... Different sources will vary the recharge time, one charger may charge the device to near full in a significantly shorter time than another device, causing you to have to recharge sooner or more often. Charging very fast, such as Quick Charge, can have a negative impact on the long term life of the battery itself.

Comment: Thanks, so will fast charging or slow charging provide more battery life after  unplugging from the charger?

Comment: And what if I charge the device a bit with one charger and a little with another charger?

Comment: @DevinErsoy I don't think you understand... It doesn't matter if you change the charger 5 times at every 20% mark or charge with the same charger... the chargers will charge at a different rate, one might charge 1% per minute and another 10% per hour, if the battery is charged by 50%, it is 50% more charge. it doesn't matter how it gets there (within reason).